# Django FactoryBoy - random choice not working with LazyFunction

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm building a number of tests for our django application and I'm using FactoryBoy

The `Profile` model has a `gender` field which is defined as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

  GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (u'm', _(u'Male')),
    (u'f', _(u'Female')),
  ) 

 gender = models.CharField(
   max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, verbose_name=_("Gender"),
   null=True, blank=True
 )
```

I wanted to randomize the value of this field in factory boy with the following line of code:

```
class ProfileFactory(factory.Factory):
   (...)
   gender = factory.LazyFunction(random.choice(['f', 'm']))
```

However, this throws a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` error
Using an old blogpost I then tried the following solution, which worked:

`gender = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda x: random.choice(['f', 'm']))`

This solved the problem, but its unclear to me why it did.

The [documentation](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#lazyfunction) for `factory.LazyFunction` states that:

```
The LazyFunction is the simplest case where the value of an attribute
 does not depend on the object being built.

It takes as argument a method to call (function, lambda…); that method 
should not take any argument, though keyword arguments are safe but 
unused, and return a value.
```

It was my understanding that `random.choice(['f', 'm'])` constituted a method call and thus should work as I expected it to.

But as it did not my understanding of `LazyFunction` is clearly flawed and I was hoping somebody could explain what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LazyFunction` requires a **callable**: something that it can call.

`random.choice(['f', 'm'])` returns a string; to make it a callable, the solution is `LazyFunction(lambda: random.choice(['f', 'm']))`.

However, the best solution to your issue is to use `factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice`, designed specifically for your usecase:

`gender = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(['f', 'm'])`

This will perform the random calls on its own, and supports proper seeding/randomness management — see https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#randomness-management for details.

Answer (score 8):

The difference between the two is that

```
lambda x: random.choice(['f', 'm'])
```

returns a function and

```
random.choice(['f', 'm'])
```

evaluates the statement and returns the string.

If you were to replicate the behavior without lambda, you could do so with

```
def foo():
  return random.choice(['f', 'm'])

# ...
gender = factory.LazyFunction(foo)
```